# Como fazer um INNER JOIN trazendo tudo de duas tabelas e mais um "max" em um campo específico?

Tags: sql, query, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Bom pessoal, para ser mais específico eu tenho duas tabelas,. tabela 01:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

...e tabela 02:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

...e gostaria de fazer um "select" trazendo tudo dessas duas tabelas, mas onde no campo "pontos" (tabela 02) tiver o maior numero de pontos, como fazer isso?

Ex.: Alex Bernardes, 20,00, 15,00, 35,00, 01/11/2017 e os pontos: 110.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este caso você deve usar sub-query, para que você pegue apenas o maior da tabela 2.

```
SELECT tabela1.*,tabela2.* FROM tabela1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tabela2 WHERE pontos = (SELECT MAX(pontos) FROM tabela2)) as tabela2 ON tabela1.Id = tabela2.garcom_id ;
```

Comment: Valeu vou tentar e posto aqui se resolveu.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tabela1.*, tabela2.pontos, tabela2.garcom_id FROM tabela1 JOIN tabela2 WHERE tabela2.garcom_id = tabela1.id
```

Assim você faz o join das 2 tabelas, retornando somente os pontos e o campo garcom_id (é necessário para fazer a comparação).

Comment: Então é conforme o ex. que eu postei junto c/ a pergunta: 
Ex.: Alex Bernardes, 20,00, 15,00, 35,00, 01/11/2017 e os pontos: 110.
Na verdade não é tudo da tabela 02 é só os pontos correspondente ao garçom da tabela 01...

Comment: haaa entendi, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: atendeu sua necessidade @RafaelSouzaCalearo ?

Answer (score 0):

Basta você fazer um `SELECT` utilizando a cláusula `INNER JOIN`, que funciona para uma junção de duas ou mais tabelas. Portanto, vou deixar abaixo um exemplo de como você deverá fazer para unir as tabelas trazendo somente o campo `pontos` da tabela 2

```
SELECT tabela1.*, tabela2.pontos, FROM tabela1 INNER JOIN tabela2 WHERE tabela1.id = tabela.garcom_id
```

Lembrando que o `.*` é para indicar que trará todos os registros da tabela 1

Comment: Ok, resolvi... Vou postar a resposta!